# Get events from nextSyncToken

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Calendar v3 API and fetching user all calendar ids and calendar events. First time when i log in then API gives me all calendars list, events from all calendars and nextSyncToken. With the help of nextSyncToken, according to Google i can get calendar events any time in the future but i am trying to get calendar events using this nextSyncToken but i am getting nothing.

so here my question is how to get calendar events from nextSyncToken?

I am using API for PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using nextSyncToken would only give you the events which have changed since you did the previous sync. 
so WITHOUT the nextSyncToken,Google would do a FULL sync and then give a nextSyncToken which can then be used for incremental syncs, which would only give the list of events which have changed.

to test this, do a sync and store the nextSyncToken, go back to Google Calendar and make some changes to 1 event and then make a call using the nextSyncToken. You should get the 1 event which you changed.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to CoffeeBeans answer + there is a Java example of how to use sync tokens for events on github: https://github.com/googlesamples/calendar-sync/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/calendar/sync/SyncTokenSample.java and howto guide here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

Sync tokens are per collection so make sure to use the sync token you got from the full sync of events to retrieve new events and the sync token from calendar list to retrieve new calendar list entries.